# Fujifilm Instax mini 90 lens cover won’t close

Tags: lens, fujifilm, camera

My mini 90 neo classic camera lens cover won’t close when turned off. Please help

To note: took it to the beach to take some pictures and there was a storm happening and lots of sand was blowing through the air.
[image]